# Won't boot into Windows after partitioning with ubuntu installer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

So I tried to install Ubuntu on my Dell laptop and I wanted to create a separate partition. I took away some free space from another partition already created. The space was listed as unusable, so I reallocated all of it in the previous partition which I took from. Then I tried to boot into Windows to transfer my data from a partition so I can format it to install Ubuntu. The funny thing is, it won't boot. It keeps on loading, nothing happens. After a force shut down, it entered the repairing tool and I got an error, which said that I can shut down or I can go into advanced settings and the following text:

```
logfile\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt
```

So I searched a bit through the common problems and I found some solved through cmd. I typed these:

```
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootrec.exe /fixboot
```

Still can't boot. Then I typed these in `diskpart`:

```
select disk 0
select partition 1
active
extend filesystem
```

Then again the 3 other `bootrec` commands listed above. Didn't work either. So I found another solution and typed:

```
bootrec rebuildbcd 
rem didn't find any windows installations, not here, not above
bcdedit /export c:\bcdbackup
attrib c:\boot\bcd -h -r -s
ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
bootrec /rebuildbcd
rem found 2 windows installations, pressed Y for both
```

Now it tells me that the operating system has failed to start multiple times and I need to reinstall the it with an installation media, which I currently don't have, alongside this error: 0xc0000001. Tried to boot into Safe Mode. Same thing, it keeps on loading and nothing happens. I have Windows 10 and Windows 7 installed, so I can easily boot into Windows 7, if needed. There are also 3 partitions, only 2 of them visible in 7.

The main problem would be that I can't boot into Windows 10. What can I do?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? What model Dell? Most Windows 10 are UEFI/gpt, but most Windows 7 are BIOS/MBR. But each can be installed in either mode. And  if you convert partitioning then Windows will not work. May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Dell Latitude E5530, has BIOS. I can't connect to the internet through ubuntu, "no wifi adapter found". So I can't use the Boot-Info or Boot-Repair.

Comment: You can create a [stand-alone Boot-Repair image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A1st_option_:_get_a_disk_including_Boot-Repair) that doesn’t require working internet access in Linux.

Comment: 1. The Bootrec.exe command group must be run from Windows installation media. Don't you have any Windows CD available?  2. If you need to just backup some data, you can use your Ubuntu live dvd to boot, mount the said partition and copy the data to external device. 3. If you install Ubuntu and put the grub on the root of the hdd, you can use all OS installed.